# Converter pra decimal sem adicionar zeros - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo, conversão

Estou convertendo um número de varchar para decimal. Esse número já tem as casas depois da vírgula, e quando converto ele adiciona mais 2 zeros.

Exemplo: 12.345,67 ---> 1234567,00

O código que estou usando é esse:
CAST(REPLACE( REPLACE(ZMI058.Montante, ',', ''), '.', '') AS decimal(18,2)) AS Montante

Como eu faço para jogar os números que já tenho para as casas decimais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O número deve ter esse formato '12345.67', por isso primeiro remova o ponto, depois substitua a vírgula por ponto, assim:

```
select CAST(REPLACE( REPLACE(ZMI058.Montante, '.', ''), ',', '.') AS decimal(18,2)) AS Montante
```

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e0e9/1

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!